# iOS - error parsing JSON created using UTF8Encoding and sent as C string

Tags: ios, objective-c

- I need to send JSON data across network and then read it back.
- I need to go thru following steps
- I have a `NSDictionary dict`

  ```
  {
    "key1" : "value1"
    "key2" : "value2"
    "key3" : "value3"
    "key4" : "value4"
  }
  ```

First I do:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];
```

Then I do

```
  NSString *stringInJSONFormat = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

which gives me following output. I validate using http://jsonlint.com/

```
__NSCFString *  @"{\n  \"key1\" : \"value1\",\n  \"key2\" : \"value2\",\n  \"key3\" : \"value3\",\n  \"key4\" : \"value4\"\n}"  0x00007f7fe2cebfb0
```

Now to send the data across,  I need to do (using a third party lib):

`[myNSString UTF8String]` and send

Now the string I get back on the receiving side is

```
__NSCFString *  @"{\\n  \"key1\" : \"value1\"\\,\\n  \"key2\" : \"value2\"\\,\\n  \"key3\" : \"value3\"\\,\\n  \"key4\" : \"value4\"\\n}"   0x00007fb0858e7190
```

And I can not de-serialize this string into valid JSON.

I do

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myNSString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&error]
```

I suspect that the third-party lib is doing its own data escaping which is leading to this issue. But I am not sure.

Would you be able to point me to issue and a possible solution?

I get error

> errorDesc __NSCFString *  @"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
>   \"Invalid escape sequence around character 1.\"
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid escape sequence around character
>   1.}"  0x00007fff5293deb0

Comment: Does the third party lib need all that unnecessary whitespace in the string?  Just don't pass the `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` option

Comment: I tried that but comma is still an issue..

Comment: Tested your code on my computer and it worked without an issue.

Comment: I get error error errorDesc __NSCFString * @"Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 \"Invalid escape sequence around character 1.\" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid escape sequence around character 1.}" 0x00007fff5293deb0

Comment: The code is supposed to work. Maybe the source dictionary is not really a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your lib converts `\n` to `\\n` and `,` to `\,`, breaking the parser. I'd suggest you to try doing

```
str = [[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n"
                                      withString:@"\n"]
       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\,"
                                 withString:@","];
```

to see if it will help.

That's a pretty strange problem, but it addresses your immediate input example. You might want to dig further into the third-party lib to see if it's the onlt data corruption.

Comment: I will do both your suggestions and will update this post.

Comment: Don't forget that this is actually a "hack", I highly recommend you to debug the issue with thirdparty lib to figure the actual bug. The problem is that a stupid string replace will modify all textual data, including one in json strings So if there is a valid string containing `\,`, it will be "fixed" by replace too.

Comment: I did follow-up and waiting for response